# In Scilab sum(matrix1) gives wrong answer

Tags: sum, scilab

Using the Scilab console, I have read in (via imread) an image to create a 256x256 matrix of integers which I named matrix1. I wish to know the sum of all the elements which should be in the region of 3,000,000 but it consistently returns the number 227. On another similar (though different) image it returns 189 so it's doing something. What am I doing wrong?

```
sum(matrix1)

ans.
= 227
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer myself. The initial matrix was of 8 bit precision numbers only and I did not realise that this precision would be retained when carrying out the "sum" function. All examples are trivial with small arrays of numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. Carrying out sum(int32(matrix1)) returned the correct value. Int32 converts the 8 bit precision to 32 bit precision and then the sum retains that precision.